# Vue store multiple values as an array

Tags: arrays, vue.js

Is there a way to store multiple values in data return when its been submitted.

View

```
<div id="app">
  <input type="text" v-model="inserted" placeholder="Insert Name">
  <button type="submit" v-on:click='submit();'>SUBMIT</button>
</div>
```

Script

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
   inserted:[], /** each name submitted should be stored over here **/
   /** if the first name was submitted as DAVID and second name was submitted as JOHN **/
   /** inserted[] should consists of both values as ["DAVID", "JOHN"] **/
  },
  methods: {
    submit(){
    console.log('value submitted');
    }
  }
})
```

Below is my code on `JSFIDDLE`

https://jsfiddle.net/ujjumaki/ypbc2vf6/12/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Took me longer then [Nino](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61895857/7505395) but here is a working full example with some added validation so you do not add empty names:

---

You can create the input for some other kind of vue variable, f.e. `name`. In `submit()` you add that to your array if it is not empty:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
   inserted:[], /* each name submitted should be stored over here */
   /* if the first name was submitted as DAVID and second name was submitted as JOHN*/
   /* inserted[] should consists of both values as ["DAVID", "JOHN"] */
   name: "",
  },
  methods: {
   submit() {
      if (this.name.length > 0) { 
        this.inserted.push(this.name);
    }
    }
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#app {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

li {
  margin: 8px 0;
}

h2 {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

del {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input type="array" v-model="name" placeholder="Insert Name">
  <button type="submit" @click='submit();'>SUBMIT</button>
  
  <p>Message is: {{ inserted }}</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Sure, just bind your input to a `toInsert` data property instead, and push it to `inserted` on submit:

```html
<input v-model="inserted">
<button @click="submit">submit</button>
```

```js
new Vue({
  data: {
    inserted: [],
    toInsert: '',
  },
  methods: {
    submit() {

      // save the value
      this.inserted.push(this.toInsert);

      // clean the input
      this.toInsert = '';

    }
  }
});
```